# Gtk/Glade How to change window content

Tags: gtk, gtk3, glade

I Want to change whole window content after button press. What is the best way to do that? Someting like "Next" button on installers but with custom buttons.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want a [GtkStack](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkStack.html) with your own buttons to change the visible child (but do have a look at GtkStackSwitcher and GtkAssistant for more ready-made but less flexible solutions).

Comment: Gtk.Notebook also look interesting.